# Facing room db backup issues missing few record in table

Tags: android, android-room

I am facing room database backup issues after taking the backup of db few record is missing in the table any one have any idea please suggest me.

steps: I have taken the latest db file and created zip of that file after zipped i have sent to the cloud with the help of network call operation there I observed few record was missing in table.

Below is the code for zipping the db file.

```
  private fun createZipBackup(files : Array<String>): String {
    return try {
        var origin : BufferedInputStream?
        val file = createTempFile().toFile()
        val fos = FileOutputStream(file)
        val out = ZipOutputStream(fos)
        val data = ByteArray(BUFFER)
        for (i in files.indices) {
            sendAnalytic("Compress - Adding: " + files[i])
            val fi = FileInputStream(files[i])
            origin = BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER)
            val entry = ZipEntry(files[i].substring(files[i].lastIndexOf("/") + 1))
            out.putNextEntry(entry)
            var count: Int
            while (origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER).also { count = it } != -1) {
                out.write(data, 0, count)
            }
            out.closeEntry()
            origin.close()
        }
        out.close()
        fos.close()
        sendAnalytic("Size for backup file ${file.length()}")
        file.absolutePath
    } catch (e : Exception) {
        sendAnalytic("Create Zip Backup Error", e.message)
        e.printStackTrace()
        ""
    }
}
```

Comment: it will be great if you share your code what you have worked on till now

Comment: Could be that you are not backing up the -wal file or more correctly not properly checkpointing the db prior to backup. The -wal file is effectively part of the database, changes are written to the -wal file, checkpoint writes changes to actual db file. see https://sqlite.org/wal.html. Not fully checkpointed (close  db should do this) then backup -wal file as well as db file, fully checkpointed then ok to just backup the db file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is the best practices for creating the backup room database file and sending to the server?

Comment: @SimonHarvan, I have added zipping code pls check

Comment: @ᴅᴇʙᴊᴇᴇᴛ please check now.